# Proper way to link existing user with facebook account

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com as a backend for an app, and while the API guide and quick start guides are helpful, I just can't seem to get facebook<->user linking to work.

In the app, I have two sign in buttons.. one for entering the users number and password, the other to log in using facebook.  The facebook login works great, and allows users to begin using social features of the app.   The problem is when they log in with just phone number/password.

Here's my linking button code:

```
 linkUser(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());


private void linkUser(final ParseUser user) {
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("email", Permissions.User.ABOUT_ME);
if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
  ParseFacebookUtils.link(user, permissions, this, new SaveCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException ex) {

      if (ex == null) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "No Exception!!");

        if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
          Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
        }
      } else {
        Log.d("MyApp", ex.getMessage());
      }

    }
  });
} else {
  Log.d("MyApp", "user already link in with Facebook!");
}
```

If i clear my app's cache, and do a fresh install, i log in first with a dummy user I created in the Parse backend, and then click the "link" button.  I look at logcat, but never see any log lines indicating user was linked or not..it's as if the "done" code never fires.  I also log in to parse and look at the fbAuth data, to see if the users facebook id shows up...nothing.

The one thing that I may/may not be doing rihgt, is finishing the auth workflow, which is supposed to be in the onActivityResult method.  I put this in my calling activity (Preferences):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == 11000) {
} else {
  ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

My understanding of the link feature, is that you can take a regular parse user, log them in (phone number, email/pass, etc) then once you have that ParseUser cached, then link to facebook using SSO and the users facebook credentials via either the facebook app, or a web page.  parsefacebookutils.link then ties the facebook user to your parse user, so that they are linked in the back end.  That way your regular user can start using facebook features.  Is this correct?

I really hate asking for code, but if anyone has utilized this feature, can you share how you did it, or point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is too late but the answer may help someone who needs it. Me too got the same problem and i tried the below code and it worked for me. See the link for more [help](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers-link).

Include the following code in the activity in which the facebook linking code used.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
              if (requestCode == com.facebook.Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE)
               ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```